# .htaccess rewrite affects the url of html image source

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a link like `www.mywebsite.com/phpfile/uservalue/` to `www.mywebsite.com/phpfile.php?param=uservalue`

So my .htaccess file is

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^phpfile/(\w*)$ ./phpfile.php?param=$1
```

The redirect works well. Now I have a problem.
My phpfile.php contains the following html code among other things

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<img src="logo.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Now if I enter `www.mywebsite.com/phpfile.php?param=uservalue` in the browser, the image loads.  But if I enter `www.mywebsite.com/phpfile/uservalue/` the image does not load.

On inspecting the element, I found that, the php was trying to load `http://mywebsite.com/phpfile/logo.png` when the image is actually in `http://mywebsite.com/logo.png`

How do I prevent the extra 'phpfile' folder being added to the image url?

Comment: The image loading isn't related to PHP, it is a *client-side browser's job*. They are loading according to your relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using relative url instead of `<img src="logo.png"/>` use `<img src="www.mywebsite.com/logo.png"/>"` and you will have no problem in the future.

or if you want can use `base` element this way 
`<base href="http://www.mywebsite.com">` and you can use it the same way you are using it `<img src="logo.png"/>`

Comment: I always use a path like `/logo.png` because it doesn't depend on the domain and protocol, and works under all "URL sub-directories".

Comment: yes it is true, but maybe he is using php he can generate that dinamically depends on the server i guess.